# heroku deployment issue with recognizing paths - works in dev-

Tags: reactjs, heroku, vite, mern, heroku-cli

im having an issue with a mern stack project using vite i am trying to deploy to heroku. the project works fine in dev mode locally however when i deploy it to heroku it cant seem to find the right path.

```
2023-07-05T21:57:28.078009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-07-05T21:57:32.569222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd ../server && npm install && npm start`
2023-07-05T21:58:04.327446+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-05T21:58:04.327468+00:00 app[web.1]: added 198 packages, and audited 199 packages in 30s
2023-07-05T21:58:04.327740+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-05T21:58:04.327782+00:00 app[web.1]: 32 packages are looking for funding
2023-07-05T21:58:04.327802+00:00 app[web.1]: run `npm fund` for details
2023-07-05T21:58:04.330214+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-05T21:58:04.330221+00:00 app[web.1]: found 0 vulnerabilities
2023-07-05T21:58:04.331207+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-05T21:58:04.331245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 9.8.0
2023-07-05T21:58:04.331294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.0>
2023-07-05T21:58:04.331323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.0` to update!
2023-07-05T21:58:04.331345+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-05T21:58:08.510616+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-05T21:58:08.510642+00:00 app[web.1]: > client@0.0.0 build
2023-07-05T21:58:08.510642+00:00 app[web.1]: > vite build
2023-07-05T21:58:08.510642+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-05T21:58:09.128460+00:00 app[web.1]: vite v4.3.9 building for production...
2023-07-05T21:58:09.172401+00:00 app[web.1]: transforming...
2023-07-05T21:58:09.672862+00:00 app[web.1]: ✓ 24 modules transformed.
2023-07-05T21:58:09.673020+00:00 app[web.1]: ✓ built in 542ms
2023-07-05T21:58:09.673212+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not resolve "./Components/NavBar/NavBar" from "src/App.jsx"
2023-07-05T21:58:09.673213+00:00 app[web.1]: file: /app/client/src/App.jsx
2023-07-05T21:58:09.675983+00:00 app[web.1]: error during build:
2023-07-05T21:58:09.675984+00:00 app[web.1]: RollupError: Could not resolve "./Components/NavBar/NavBar" from "src/App.jsx"
2023-07-05T21:58:09.675984+00:00 app[web.1]: at error (file:///app/client/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
2023-07-05T21:58:09.676031+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///app/client/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24632:24)
2023-07-05T21:58:09.676189+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/client/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24594:26
2023-07-05T21:58:10.064679+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2023-07-05T21:58:10.255533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2023-07-05T21:58:10.285342+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

here is the error and heres is the app.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import "./index.css";
import { HomePage } from "./Pages/Home/home";
import CreateSpecForm from "./Components/CreateSpecForm/createSpecForm";
import RecipeDetailsPage from "./Pages/RecipeDetailsPage/RecipeDetailsPage";
import EditSpecForm from "./Pages/EditSpecForm/EditSpecForm";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar/NavBar";
import { LandingPage } from "./Pages/LandingPage/LandingPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route exact path="/create" element={<CreateSpecForm />} />
        <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<RecipeDetailsPage />} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditSpecForm />} />
        <Route path="/landing" element={<LandingPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;

it doesn't seem to an issue with the import as again it works locally?

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./NavBar.css";

export const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navBar">
      <div>
        <Link className="logo" to="/">
          <p>SpecApp</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="options">
        <Link to="/create">
          <p className="option">Create</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <p className="option">thesaurus</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <p className="option">Profile</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the export should be fine as a default as it is the only components that is being exported.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./NavBar.css";

export const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navBar">
      <div>
        <Link className="logo" to="/">
          <p>SpecApp</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="options">
        <Link to="/create">
          <p className="option">Create</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <p className="option">thesaurus</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/">
          <p className="option">Profile</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

could it be an issue with the vite config? or some other bundling issue?
would appreciate anyone that can point me in the right direction